# SQL Server : fulltext index very slow

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have some performance issues with my full-text search query.

```
SELECT TOP ? *
FROM Database1.Schema1.Table1 t1 
WHERE 
    (((t1.Column1 in (?)) AND t1.Column2 = ?) 
     AND (CONTAINS(t1.*, 'My Search Term 1*'))
```

The above query takes a long time to complete, but if I remove the wildcard (`*`) from my `CONTAINS` statement, it runs within a few milliseconds.

```
SELECT TOP ? *
FROM Database1.Schema1.Table1 t1 
WHERE 
    (((t1.Column1 in (?)) AND t1.Column2 = ?) 
     AND (CONTAINS(t1.*, 'My Search Term 1'))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/improve-the-performance-of-full-text-queries

Comment: I would suggest checking the execution plan for both to see if there is any difference. That may hint at what's going wrong.